# Increase precision of MATLAB variable/data point from a plot

Tags: matlab

I'm plotting a control system and I need to prove that the steady state error from MATLAB coincides with my calculations.

My calculations have given me `0.000833333`, and on the plot, the data-tip markers have very little precision (no decimal points at the location I selected).

However I can right-click the marker and select `Export cursor data to workspace...`

This gives me the position location of `X=98.0037`, `Y=98.0028`

That gives me an error of `0.0009`, so it's not quite the `0.00083333` from calculations.  I know this is correct however, I just would like to know how to increase the precision of the variables/data points from plot past 4 decimal places if possible.

[image]

Comment: type `format long` in your console, then look at your exported cursor position again.

Comment: Ah there we go! I also realized all i needed to do was actually click within the array and that works as well. Thanks a lot. Feel free to write that out as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different routes to get more precisions from these data tip cursors:

### 1) Export manually:

As you mentioned in your question, right click on the datatip then select `Export cursor data to workspace...`. Let's assume you export that in the default variable `cursor_info`, you then get a structure with 3 fields:

```
cursor_info = 
       Target: 492.0040
     Position: [7.3593e+05 10.6353]
    DataIndex: 7
```

`Target` is the handle of the `line` object to which the cursor was *snapped*
`Position` is a 1x2 vector giving the `x` and `y` coordinates of the selected data points  (it will have a third value if the `z` coordinates are defined)
`DataIndex` is the index of the selected data point coordinates in the array that was used to plot the line. So you could also ask for :

```
>> x(7) %// or "x(cursor_info.DataIndex)" would be the same
ans =
   7.3593e+05
>> y(7)
ans =
   11.3200
```

Now by default the display of values in the console is limited to a few digits, but the number in the variable has more precision. 2 ways to display more precision:

First method is to type `format long` in the console. After that all your numeric output in the console will be with 15 digits:

```
>> cursor_info.Position
ans =
   1.0e+05 *
   7.359289702215524   0.000106353183026
```

Second method is to force the precision you desire by using a format specifier and `sprintf` or `fprintf`:

```
>> fprintf('x=%15.15d y=%g \n',cursor_info.Position)
x=7.359289702215524e+05 y=10.6353
```

### 2) Export programatically

Alternatively to the manual export of the `cursor_info` data, you can call that with code:

```
dcm = datacursormode(gcf) ;
cursor_info = dcm.getCursorInfo ;
```

You then get the same `cursor_info` variable than if you exported it manually. Displaying the values can be done the same way than above.

### 3) Direct display (at the wanted precision).

You can also achieve a full customization of what the data tip will display, not only the position but also some calculated or converted values. Right click on the data tip and select `Edit text update function`. This will open an editor window with the current code for the data tip, which basically query the data tip position and create a cell array of text to be displayed. Modify this function to your needs then save it somewhere you can retrieve it.

For an example with the data I was using, I display the `x` and `y` coordinates with different precision, then a calculation based on the 2 values, and I also convert the `x` coordinates to the date representation.

```
function output_txt = myModifiedDatatip(obj,event_obj)

pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
output_txt = {['X: ',num2str(pos(1),12)],... %// default code, only the output precision is changed
              ['Y: ',num2str(pos(2),8)]};

%// add all the informations you want to calculate and display directly here:
output_txt{end+1} = ['error (y-x): ',sprintf('%16f', pos(2)-pos(1))]; %// difference between x and x
output_txt{end+1} = ['Date: ', datestr(pos(1))]; %// display the date/time
```

This example will display a data tip like so:
[image: datatip]

After that, on any subsequent plot or figure, you can re-apply this data tip format by right clicking on a data tip, `select text update function`, then point to the data tip function you saved earlier.